# Move towards mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying move an object towards my mouse using velocity when clicked, but when I click the object usually goes in a different direction. I basically copied the code from another project, and in that project it works. The only difference is that in the other Project instead of setting velocity, I use `AddForce`. What is causing this to do what it is doing?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public float shootDelay = 0.03f;
    public GameObject[] balls;
    bool hasShot = false;

    Vector3 clickPosition = Vector3.zero;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && !hasShot) {
            hasShot = true;
            Vector3 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 direction = point - transform.position;
            StartCoroutine(Shoot(direction));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Shoot(Vector2 direction) {
        foreach (GameObject ball in balls) {
            float speed = ball.GetComponent<Ball>().speed;
            ball.GetComponent<Ball>().rb.velocity = direction.normalized * speed;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(shootDelay);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the direction vector, either here:

```
Vector2 direction = transform.position - point;
```

Or here:

```
ball.GetComponent<Ball>().rb.velocity = -direction.normalized * speed;
```

Comment: Neither of those fix it.

Comment: Try using [Gizmos.DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawLine.html) to identify whether the `direction` is even correct.

Comment: Figured it out, I was using `transform.position` of the manager object instead of `ball[0].transform.postion` of the actual ball.